# Compare two rows in MySQL to change value of third row value

Tags: mysql

I have three columns that are showing 0 in a table. If the first two columns are both 0, I would like to change the value of the third column to something else other than 0 (like N/A, or another value). Is this possible in MySQL? Still learning the ropes and appreciate the help from the community so much!

**What I have now:**

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

**What I am trying to do:**

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | N/A |

Comment: How about a simple `UPDATE` statement?  Something like `UPDATE mytable SET columnC = 'N/A' WHERE columnA = 0 AND columnB = 0`

Comment: Your title says rows, did you mean columns?

Comment: What is the datatype of column C? You can't use `N/A` if it's a numeric type. You could use `NULL`.

Comment: Barmar yes sorry. I was worried about the N/A.

Comment: Column C is decimal(4,1)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).